# Symfony2 DataTransformers - How do you transform back without ID or unique values?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a collection of PhoneNumber entities for each Contact (Name, Email) entity. PhoneNumber is broken down into area code, exchange, suffix, extension, and then a type selector (Work, Home, Mobile). I want to use a DataTransformer so that the number can display in a single form field instead of 4 different text boxes. The phonenumbers are not unique within the database.

**UPDATED:** How do I access the the full entity when transforming from the string version back to the Entity? I previously ran into this problem and ended up putting the entity's ID inside of brackets within the text field and then regexed them out in the transform so that I could do a query to get the entity.

The phonenumber_combined is a custom form type service that references my PhoneNumberCombinedType class.

**My add method for the collection of Phones within Contact:**

```
->add('phones', 'collection', array(
            'label'     => 'Phones',
            'type'      => new PhoneNumberType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true
            ))
        ;
```

**PhoneNumberType buildForm function:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('phone', 'phonenumber_combined')
        ->add('type', 'entity',
            array('class'   => 'Test\Bundle\SystemBundle\Entity\Type',
            'property'      => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('type')
                ->where('type.type = :t')
                ->orderBy('type.name', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('t', 'PhoneNumber');
            }))
        ;           
}
```

**The PhoneNumberCombinedType service:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new PhoneNumberToStringTransformer($this->om);

    $builder->addViewTransformer($transformer);
}
```

**PhoneNumberToStringTransformer:**

```
public function transform($phonenumber)
{
    if (null === $phonenumber) {
        return null;
    }

    return $phonenumber->__toString();       
}

public function reverseTransform($phonenumber)
{
    if (!$phonenumber) {
        return null;
    } 

    // PHONE NUMBER IS JUST A STRING AT THIS POINT, HOW DO I GET THE ENTITY?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of updates but I have found a decent solution to this problem. I added a **setPhone method to the PhoneNumber entity that seems to be called automatically after the reverse transform**. In my transformer, I added a regex to split my phone number into its respective sections and then added each section to an array. This array is returned by the transformer which is then used by setPhone to update the PhoneNumber object.

**My setPhone method in the PhoneNumber entity:**

```
/**
 * Used by PhoneNumberToStringTransformer to set Entity data
 * @param array $phone_data
 */
public function setPhone($phone_data)
{
    if($phone_data == null) {
        $this->setAreaCode(null);
        $this->setExchange(null);
        $this->setSuffix(null);
        $this->setExtension(null);
        return $this;
    }

    $this->setAreaCode($phone_data['AreaCode']);
    $this->setExchange($phone_data['Exchange']);
    $this->setSuffix($phone_data['Suffix']);
    $this->setExtension($phone_data['Extension']);

    return $this;
}
```

**The reverseTransform in my PhoneNumberToStringTransformer:**

```
/**
 * Transforms a phonenumber string to an array that will be passed to setPhone
 * which will handle setting each entity field.
 *
 * @param  string $string Phone number string
 * @return (array) areaCode, exchange, suffix and extension
 */
public function reverseTransform($string)
{
    if (!$string || strlen($string) == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    // Split phone number into array for areaCode, exchange, suffix, and extension
    $pattern = '/(\d{3})?-?(\d{3})?-?(\d{4})?( x(\d+))?/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    $phone_data = array('AreaCode'=>null, 'Exchange'=>null, 'Suffix'=>null, 'Extension'=>null);

    $counter = 1;
    foreach($phone_data as $key => $value) {
        if($counter == 4)
            $counter = 5;

        if(isset($matches[$counter][0]) && $matches[$counter][0] !== '') {
            $phone_data[$key] = $matches[$counter][0];
        } else {
            $phone_data[$key] = null;
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    return $phone_data;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to pass an object manager via constructor injection then operate on that like you normally would.

```
class PhoneNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function transform($phonenumber)
    {
        if ($phonenumber === null) {
            return null;
        }

        return $phonenumber->__toString();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($phonenumber)
    {
        if (!$this->phonenumber) {
            return null;
        }

        $phoneEntity = $this->om
            ->getRepository('{REFERENCE_TO_THE_ENTITY}')
            ->findOneBy(array('phonenumber' => $phonenumber));

        if ($phoneEntity === null) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException();
        }

        return $phoneEntity;
    }
}
```